# Integrating class in PHP

Tags: php, class

I have looked at various forum software and am attempting to replicate an idea. This is to get me better at using classes with PHP, however, this is one of my first time using classes. I'm creating a class that will allow me to pull information from the database in a simple, one lined command. I understand most people will say this is not a good idea, however, this line will not be used when users insert data.

Here is the class:

```
$db = new DB_MySQLi;

class DB_MySQLi
{

    function simple_select($table, $fields="*", $conditions="", $options=array())
    {
        $query = "SELECT ".$fields." FROM ".$this->table_prefix.$table;

        if($conditions != "")
        {
            $query .= " WHERE ".$conditions;
        }

        if(isset($options['group_by']))
        {
            $query .= " GROUP BY ".$options['group_by'];
        }

        if(isset($options['order_by']))
        {
            $query .= " ORDER BY ".$options['order_by'];
            if(isset($options['order_dir']))
            {
                $query .= " ".my_strtoupper($options['order_dir']);
            }
        }

        if(isset($options['limit_start']) && isset($options['limit']))
        {
            $query .= " LIMIT ".$options['limit_start'].", ".$options['limit'];
        }
        else if(isset($options['limit']))
        {
            $query .= " LIMIT ".$options['limit'];
        }

        return $this->query($query);
    }


}
```

And whenever I try to run a query like this:

```
$query = $db->simple_select("users", "*");
```

I get these errors:
Notice: Undefined property: DB_MySQLi::$table_prefix 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB_MySQLi::query()

How come DB_MySQLi is undefined?

Comment: `DB_MySQLi` isn't undefined. You're trying to call `query()` on a class, `DB_MySQLi`, which doesn't have a `query()` method. Did you mean to extend `PDO`, or use some sort of instance variable to store a database connection?

Comment: I have $db = new DB_MySQLi; in the code

Comment: That's just your database wrapper. It isn't a database connection—PHP doesn't know what database you're using, where it is, or how to log into it. That's what [`PDO`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [`MySQLi`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) are for. They handle the gritty work of database connections and querying, and contain `query()` methods which you can use for your wrapper class.

Comment: If that's your entire `DB_MySQLi` class, you have no way of telling PHP how to actually handle your database. You're just expecting it to know how to connect, authenticate with, and operate on some arbitrary database, which it can't.

Comment: Do I need to do my connection inside the class? I have it linked in config.php

Comment: If it's defined in `config.php`, you should construct your instance of `DB_MySQLi` with that database object. Add a constructor that takes your connection, and store it as `$this->db` in your `DB_MySQLi` class. Then, instead of doing `$this->query(...)`, use `$this->db->query(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

`DB_MySQLi` is not undefined, `DB_MySQLi::query()` is.

`return $this->query($query);` - when you tell PHP to use `$this->`, you're calling inside the scope of the class (that particular instance of the class). In this case, you don't have a method called `query` inside your `DB_MySQLi` class; so it can't find it and hence throws the error.

Comment: But when I add "$db = new DB_MySQLi;" how come that doesn't do anything?